# MVC 5 NHibernate Autofac, not able to see database data

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I'm building an MVC5 web app connecting to a MS SQL 2008 database, so that the users can search and make changes to data stored there.  I've looked at a bunch of autofac tutorials and examples, but can't seem to make any of them work.

I'm assuming my autofac configuration is the problem, because when I run the app it says my model is null.  Which I think means the autofac is not connecting to the datbase.

So, in my `global.asax.cs` file I have the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        #region Autofac
        // Register Controllers
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly); //all controllers in assembly at once ?            
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

        // Set the Dependency Resolver
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        // Register Model Binders
        builder.RegisterModelBinders(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly); //all binders in assembly at once ?
        builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

        // Register Modules
        builder.RegisterModule<PersistenceModule>();           

        #endregion

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


    }
```

I have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=DEVSRV\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=tipdemo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=***********</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
      <!--<mapping assembly="NHibernateTest"/> -->
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

And my `PersistenceModule` class is:

```
public class PersistenceModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("builder", "builder is null");

            base.Load(builder);
        }


        private ISessionFactory ConfigureDB()
        {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().Configure(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Config/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
            cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Domain.General.Project).Assembly);
            return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, I should mention that I put breakpoints in my PersistenceModule class, and it didn't enter there.

Comment: Just curious why people still use nhibernate for new development now that Entity Framework is mature and full featured...

Comment: I tried using EF at first, but it was really slow and became unresponsive.  The db has about 60 tables and about 3000 records.  But its also possible I set that up wrong as well. 

Someone told me I should do it this way instead...

Comment: One of the tutorials I followed for EF was here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database

It was a good tutorial, and it works great for me using a small db, but using the pre-existing ones we have it became slow an unresponsive

Comment: Are you kidding, right @EkoostikMartin? It MUST BE a joke here. EF isn't nearly close to all set of features that NHibernates provides! Use both tools and see for yourself...

Comment: @cidico - I have used both. NHibernate multiplies my development time by three vs Entity Framework, and the performance is about 20-30% worse.

Comment: If you're working with legacy database then OK, I get it. NHibernate is really a bad choice here. If you need do build queries that are a little more complex you'll get yourself with a really bad SQL or using Views and SP's. The EF's tools to build complex query are nearly close to NHibernate's ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't register things in the container after it's built.

On line 11 in the sample for `Application_Start` you're building the container, but then after you set the `DependencyResolver` you're registering more stuff with the `ContainerBuilder`. You can't do that - you have to register everything first, then build the container as the last thing you do.

That's why it's never entering your `PersistenceModule` - you've already built the container, so it's not actually getting registered.

If, for some reason, you need to add registrations to an already-built container, you need to create an all new `ContainerBuilder` and call `builder.Update(container)`. However, I strongly recommend you just reorder things so the container is built last rather than go the `Update` route if possible.